# Testing the estimated query plan of a portion of a trigger that uses inserted/deleted

Tags: sql-server, trigger, execution-plan, sql-server-2019

I'm performance tuning a SQL Server trigger that has several statements using the "inserted" and "deleted" tables.

How can I break out those individual queries from the trigger for testing in order to see their estimated execution plans?

The "inserted" and "deleted" tables have no context outside of a trigger.  I want to make sure that it mimics the behavior of the trigger as closely as possible.

The trigger I'm testing is `INSTEAD OF DELETE`. I was hoping not to actually delete the record so that I could easily test the before and after without deleting the row.

Answer (score 0):

For testing and performance tuning purpose, you can just surround the DELETE statement with BEGIN TRANSACTION ... ROLLBACK